# How to store a set of images and labels dynamically in zarr format?

Tags: classification, image-compression, dataloader, n-dimensional, zarr

I have read zarr documentation,but could not able do this.
I want something like this tree format:

```
---dataset

    --- sample1
        --frames( 10 rgb frames)
        --labels (1/0)

    --- sample2
        --frames( 10 rgb frames )
        --labels (1/0)

    --- sample3
        --frames( 10 rgb frames )
        --labels (1/0)
```

Thank you.